# set keyspace PER operation

Tags: astyanax

In astyanax when you form the build you can supply a keyspace, but I need to supply the keyspace PER operation I run as different CF's may be in different keyspaces.  Is this possible at all?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Mutations are bound to a single keyspace but can span multiple column families. You could instance multiple Keyspace contexts in astyanax and use the one you need.
I tend to have one keyspace context per declare keyspace, and have each context a field of and Enum value. Very practical.